# How do I detect if script was CALL'ed or invoked directly, in Windows CMD.EXE shell?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to distinguish these two situations inside script.cmd:

```
C:\> call script.cmd
C:\> script.cmd
```

How can I determine if my script.cmd was invoked directly, or invoked in the context of using a CALL?

If it matters, this is on Windows 7.

```
@echo off
set invoked=0
rem ---magic goes here---
if %invoked%==0 echo Script invoked directly.
if %invoked%==1 echo Script invoked by a CALL.
```

Anyone know the "magic goes here" which would detect having been CALL'ed and set invoked=1?

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: It solves the problem of being able to do...
`script1.cmd && script2.cmd && script3.cmd`
...without having to do...
`call script1.cmd && call script2.cmd && call script3.cmd`

Comment: No, the indicated "problem" can not be "solved" knowing how the file is called. It is the batch interpreter who decides if the execution flow will return to the caller (when using `call`) or not (not using `call`). And in the sample code in your comment, the three files are called without problems in both cases

Comment: If script1.cmd has `@call script1_impl.cmd %*` and then script1_impl.cmd has the implementation, then the `script1 && script2 && script3` chaining with error abort will work.  Would be nice not to have to have the one script there just to do script forwarding (call'ing).  Could have it call itself with a sentinel token for %1.

Comment: @MCND The returned errorlevel of the script is honored by the CMD `&&` if the script was invoked with a `call`.  The returned errorlevel of the script is not honored by the CMD if the script was not invoked with a `call`.

Comment: Have you considered switching from cmd.exe to PowerShell?

Comment: I've included an answer/workaround. At this moment i can only test on XP and have no access to a proper debugger to see other options. Maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, I see no way to detect it, but as a workaround you can always force the use of the sentinel.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    rem If "flag" is not present, use CALL command
    if not "%~1"=="_flag_" goto :useCall
    rem Discard "flag"
    shift /1

    rem Here the main code

    set /a "randomExitCode=%random% %% 2"   
    echo [%~1] exit with code %randomExitCode%
    exit /b %randomExitCode%
    goto :eof


rem Retrieve a correct full reference to the current batch file    
:getBatchReference returnVar
    set "%~1=%~f0" & goto :eof

rem Execute     
:useCall
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    call :getBatchReference _f0
    endlocal & call "%_f0%" _flag_ %*
```

This will allow you to use the indicated syntax

```
script.cmd first && script.cmd second && script.cmd third
```

The posted code ends the script with a random exit code for testing. Execution will continue when the exit code is 0

NOTE: For it to work, at least in XP, it seems the `call` to the batch file MUST be the last code in the batch file

Comment: I ended up using the same technique.  Still seems it should be something that is accessible somehow.  Now I wish I would have taken a look at the CMD source code when I was working at Microsoft.  *sadpanda*

Comment: Word of caution, if you need to do `script1 ^| && script2 ^> && script3` the `%*` does not properly escape the escaped parameters.  In my use case, that is not an issue since my parameters are simple words.  But I just discovered that as a problem in my unit tests.  I'm probably missing a `%~*` or somesuch which will properly expand the parameters.

Comment: Too much trouble. I recommend PowerShell.

Comment: lol, I like your thinking Bill_Stewart!  Although if I were to use an alternative shell, I'd use Cygwin Bash.  Unfortunately, in this case, neither PowerShell nor Cygwin Bash are viable options.  Has to be Windows CMD shell.

Comment: Why isn't PowerShell an option? It is built into the OS on Windows 7 and later.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't run *.CMD scripts.  At least not directly, it would have to spin up a CMD.EXE shell to run them.

Comment: Or maybe I was not clear on the context.  The CMD scripts I am running are not mine.  They are the commands I need to run.  Trying to wrap those scripts with a *.PS1 scripts to work around the CMD behavior for `&&` with invoked-directly versus invoked by `call` *.CMD scripts seems a bit overkill.

Comment: PowerShell has no problem with running cmd.exe scripts. I'm not talking about wrapping anything; switch to PowerShell as your shell instead of cmd.exe. It is a much better command environment.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thank you for the suggestion.  My preferred shell environment is Bash, and I do have Cygwin Bash on my machine.  The CMD scripts I run have a lot of environmental setup and have to be run in their own CMD shell.  I have tried to port that environment to work in Bash, but it was a lot of bother with little benefit.  Upshot is that I just run those CMD script in their admin CMD shell with their zillions of environmental settings.  Maybe PowerShell would bridge that better.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the script's path is in the CMDCMDLINE variable. If not, then it was probably called.

In this example I use `%CMDCMDLINE:"=/%` to turn the quotes into forward-slashes (the FIND command can't search for quotes) and I echo it with `<NUL SET/P=""` so that certain characters in the file path (like ampersands) don't break the script.

```
<NUL SET/P="%CMDCMDLINE:"=/%" | FIND "/%~0/">NUL || (
    REM Commands to perform if script was called
    GOTO:EOF
)

::AND/OR

<NUL SET/P="%CMDCMDLINE:"=/%" | FIND "/%~0/">NUL && (
    REM Commands to perform if script was NOT called
    GOTO:EOF
)
```